# PHP Convert from 'd/m/Y - h:i:s A' to timestamp

Tags: php

I want to convert format `d/m/Y - h:i:s A` to a timestamp in PHP.

I tried:

```
$time = '26/07/2014 - 03:59:23 PM';
$time2 = strtotime($time);
```

But that returns null

Comment: `strtotime` doesn't know all formats. You can look up supported date formats here: http://php.net/manual/de/datetime.formats.php

Answer (score 1):

This is easiest when using the [`DateTime`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) class:

```
$dateString = '26/07/2014 - 03:59:23 PM';
$datetime   = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y - h:i:s A', $dateString);

echo $datetime->getTimestamp();
```

An example of this code is [here](http://ideone.com/6rSaXO).

Comment: Thank You, how I can but this 'd/m/Y - h:i:s A' format in input value type datatime-local

Comment: By using [`DateTime::format()`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php), such as: `$datetime->format('My format');`.

Comment: I did this: <input value="<? echo date('d/m/Y - h:i:s A',$row['date']) ?>" type="datetime-local" name="time"  /> But the value not shown in the form

Comment: Why would it? Use the DateTime class as specified in my answer.